# Election Query Hopefully last one

Tags: sql-server, operand

This query is working fine:

```
select  rc.[race number],
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [candidate num] end) as Winner,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then Votes end) as WinningVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then party end) as WinningParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then leader end) as Winner1,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [leader percent] end) as WinnerPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [candidate num] end) as Loser,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then Votes end) as LosingVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then party end) as LosingParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then leader2 end) as Loser2,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [leader2 percent] end) as LoserPercent

from 
(
select  rc.[race number],
        rc.[candidate num],
        rc.[Votes],
        rc.[winner],
        c.[party],
        r.[leader],
        r.[leader percent],
        r.[leader2],
        r.[leader2 percent],
            row_number() over (partition by rc.[race number] order by votes desc) as seqnum
    from    dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] rc
    inner join dbo.[CANDIDATE] c    on  rc.[candidate num]  = c.[candidate number]
    inner join dbo.[RACE] r
     on rc.[race number] = r.[race number]          
) rc
group by rc.[race number]
```

Now I have one more field from the RACE CANDIDATES TABLE that needs to show up in the query. It returns a 0 for the loser and a 1 for the winner. This column is named Winner.
When I run the following query:

```
select  rc.[race number],
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [candidate num] end) as Winner,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then Votes end) as WinningVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then party end) as WinningParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then leader end) as Winner1,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then winner end) as WinnerSelected,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [leader percent] end) as WinnerPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [candidate num] end) as Loser,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then Votes end) as LosingVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then party end) as LosingParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then leader2 end) as Loser2,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [leader2 percent] end) as LoserPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then winner end) as LoserSelected

from 
(
select  rc.[race number],
        rc.[candidate num],
        rc.[Votes],
        rc.[winner],
        c.[party],
        r.[leader],
        r.[leader percent],
        r.[leader2],
        r.[leader2 percent],
            row_number() over (partition by rc.[race number] order by votes desc) as seqnum
    from    dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] rc
    inner join dbo.[CANDIDATE] c    on  rc.[candidate num]  = c.[candidate number]
    inner join dbo.[RACE] r
     on rc.[race number] = r.[race number]          
) rc
group by rc.[race number]
```

I get an error that states: ***"Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator."***

Does this mean I may be screwed? Because in my first statement I have candidate num aliased as Winner, perhaps if I changed this it would go away. Is that what is causing the error? Or is it because of the "0" or the "1" being returned?

When I run `SELECT * FROM [RACE CANDIDATES]` it returns the winner column with the correct "0" or "1".

This is my last issue, I promise.

Thanks to all who have guided me through this disaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `BIT` column is `1` or `0`, you can't apply `MAX()` to it. The only option I saw in other forums is to cast it as `tinyint`. Like so. See if this works.

```
select  rc.[race number],
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [candidate num] end) as Winner,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then Votes end) as WinningVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then party end) as WinningParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then leader end) as Winner1,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then CAST(winner AS tinyint) end) as WinnerSelected,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [leader percent] end) as WinnerPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [candidate num] end) as Loser,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then Votes end) as LosingVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then party end) as LosingParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then leader2 end) as Loser2,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [leader2 percent] end) as LoserPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then CAST(winner AS tinyint) end) as LoserSelected

from 
(
select  rc.[race number],
        rc.[candidate num],
        rc.[Votes],
        rc.[winner],
        c.[party],
        r.[leader],
        r.[leader percent],
        r.[leader2],
        r.[leader2 percent],
            row_number() over (partition by rc.[race number] order by votes desc) as seqnum
    from    dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] rc
    inner join dbo.[CANDIDATE] c    on  rc.[candidate num]  = c.[candidate number]
    inner join dbo.[RACE] r
     on rc.[race number] = r.[race number]          
) rc
group by rc.[race number]
```

Comment: Is there a way I can get around this? While still allowing the winnerselected and loserselected column to fill one signle rowset?

Comment: now that I have looked at the URL you posted above, can I use MIN in place of max? or will that fubar the results?

Comment: I was trying to use CONVERT and was about to use CAST....but. Your query WORKED!!!!

Comment: Glad it helped! Good luck with your project.